# Can I find out if there are other browser windows running webgl?

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am creating a three.js powered website, and on some browsers (I am looking at you firefox), if other tabs are also running webGL, my performance stutters.

I would like to know if there is a way to find out (in the browser) if other tabs are consuming webgl services so that I can alert the user.

I appreciate any and all comments!

Comment: As Leeft says, No you can't. It would be a security violation. You could suggest to the user to close other WebGL tabs though really anything could make your tab stutter. They could be running 4 copies of [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/). They could be running a native game in another window. The could be watching a HD youtube video or trans streaming video to their TV. There's very little limit to the number of things they could do that might make your tab stutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be a security violation, so no, you can't do that.

**Update**:

I'll just add, you could include [stats.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/%20stats.js) (more likely, you'll need to do something very similar to establish to what stats.js is doing to get an idea of what the *average* frame rate is like and look for dips in that performance), and if that is regularly dropping then alert the user. That said, you are likely to get the calculation wrong, and there are always many variables you can't control which can affect performance. Most of those can be resolved with a browser restart, particularly Firefox doesn't seem to be releasing its GPU memory across page reloads. When that memory is full the performance drops badly.

In any case, any warnings you give out should probably not be intrusive for the user in any way.

Also note that properly written WebGL programs (using `requestAnimationFrame` as intended) should to my knowledge not be consuming much in compute resources when the tab is in the background, though this may also vary per browser. But a tab in the background will still consume the memory (GPU memory, and JavaScript code and objects).